# Finishing steps to a subplot graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm having some trouble finishing up this subplot.  All I need to do at this point is get rid of the jumble of text at the bottom, then add individual X labels for each bar in each subplot. (all subplots share the same group of X values)

Here's what I have so far...

```
dictlist = []

for i in quarters:
    d = defaultdict(int)
    x = df['Activity'][df['QuarterYear']==i].tolist()
    for j in x:
        d[j] += 1
    dictlist.append(d)
```

This returns a list with 4 dictionaries in it.  Each one with the keys and value counts for each quarter. Here's dictlist[0]

defaultdict(int,
            {'CARE COORDINATION': 11052,
             'COMPREHENSIVE CARE MANAGEMENT': 1403,
             'HEALTH PROMOTION': 6575,
             'PATIENT AND FAMILY SUPPORT': 9731,
             'REFERRAL TO SOCIAL SUPPORTS': 1888,
             'TRANSITIONAL CARE': 239})

And here's my graph code

```
f, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(7, 7), sharex=True, sharey=True)

axes[0,0].bar(dictlist[0].keys(), dictlist[0].values())
axes[0,0].set_xlabel(quarters[0])
#axes[0,0].set_xticks(range(0,7))
#axes[0,0].set_xticklabels([*dictlist[0]], fontdict=None, minor=False)
for p in axes[0,0].patches:
    axes[0,0].annotate(str(p.get_height()), xy=(p.get_x(), p.get_height()))

axes[0,1].bar(dictlist[1].keys(), dictlist[1].values())
axes[0,1].set_xlabel(quarters[1])
for p in axes[0,1].patches:
    axes[0,1].annotate(str(p.get_height()), xy=(p.get_x(), p.get_height()))

axes[1,0].bar(dictlist[2].keys(), dictlist[2].values())
axes[1,0].set_xlabel(quarters[2])
for p in axes[1,0].patches:
    axes[1,0].annotate(str(p.get_height()), xy=(p.get_x(), p.get_height()))

axes[1,1].bar(dictlist[3].keys(), dictlist[3].values())
axes[1,1].set_xlabel(quarters[3])
for p in axes[1,1].patches:
    axes[1,1].annotate(str(p.get_height()), xy=(p.get_x(), p.get_height()))

fig = plt.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches( 16, 16)
fig.savefig('output5.png')
```

[image]

I'm not exactly sure what's causing that jumbled text at the bottom, and I'd like to create a master legend somehow.  Any help would be appreciated.  This is python 3.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I so figured it out.  Here's the code that I ended up with for my code and graph.  I had to iterate over each tick, which was the part messing me up.

```
f, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(7, 7), sharey=True, sharex=True)

axes[0,0].bar([*dictlist[0].keys()], [*dictlist[0].values()])
axes[0,0].set_xlabel(quarters[0])
for p in axes[0,0].patches:
    axes[0,0].annotate(str(p.get_height()), xy=(p.get_x(), p.get_height()))
for tick in axes[0,0].get_xticklabels():
    tick.set_rotation(90)


axes[0,1].bar([*dictlist[1].keys()], [*dictlist[1].values()])
axes[0,1].set_xlabel(quarters[1])
for p in axes[0,1].patches:
    axes[0,1].annotate(str(p.get_height()), xy=(p.get_x(), p.get_height()))
for tick in axes[0,1].get_xticklabels():
    tick.set_rotation(90)


axes[1,0].bar([*dictlist[2].keys()], [*dictlist[2].values()])
axes[1,0].set_xlabel(quarters[2])
for p in axes[1,0].patches:
    axes[1,0].annotate(str(p.get_height()), xy=(p.get_x(), p.get_height()))
for tick in axes[1,0].get_xticklabels():
    tick.set_rotation(90)


axes[1,1].bar([*dictlist[3].keys()], [*dictlist[3].values()])
axes[1,1].set_xlabel(quarters[3])
for p in axes[1,1].patches:
    axes[1,1].annotate(str(p.get_height()), xy=(p.get_x(), p.get_height()))
for tick in axes[1,1].get_xticklabels():
    tick.set_rotation(90)


fig = plt.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches( 16, 16)

plt.tight_layout()
```

[image]